# Querying on key of a Map in Aerospike

Tags: aerospike, aql

I'm trying to store a map in aerospike and fetch the data based on the key of the map.

First I created a Index on the bin where i'm storing the map

```shell
 aql> create mapkeys index status on test.myset (state) String
 aql> show indexes
+--------+---------+-----------+---------+-------+-----------+---------+------------+----------+
| ns     | bin     | indextype | set     | state | indexname | path    | sync_state | type     |
+--------+---------+-----------+---------+-------+-----------+---------+------------+----------+
| "test" | "state" | "MAPKEYS" | "myset" | "RW"  | "status"  | "state" | "synced"   | "STRING" |
+--------+---------+-----------+---------+-------+-----------+---------+------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.000 secs)
OK
```

Then I used java client to store the map

```java
AerospikeClient client = new AerospikeClient("127.0.0.1",3000);

    WritePolicy writePolicy = new WritePolicy();
    writePolicy.timeout=500;

    for(int i = 1;i<10;i++){
        Key key = new Key("test","myset",""+i);
        client.delete(writePolicy, key);

        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("key1", "string1");
        map.put("key2", "string2");
        map.put("key3", "string3");

        Bin bin = new Bin("state", map);
        client.put(writePolicy, key, bin);

    }
```

I checked the data through apl and the data is clearly present.

```shell
aql> select * from test.myset
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| state                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| {"key1":"string1", "key2":"string2", "key3":"string3"} |
| {"key1":"string1", "key2":"string2", "key3":"string3"} |
| {"key1":"string1", "key2":"string2", "key3":"string3"} |
| {"key1":"string1", "key2":"string2", "key3":"string3"} |
| {"key1":"string1", "key2":"string2", "key3":"string3"} |
| {"key1":"string1", "key2":"string2", "key3":"string3"} |
| {"key1":"string1", "key2":"string2", "key3":"string3"} |
| {"key1":"string1", "key2":"string2", "key3":"string3"} |
| {"key1":"string1", "key2":"string2", "key3":"string3"} |
| {"key1":"string1", "key2":"string2", "key3":"string3"} |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.019 secs)
```

Now when I try to query based on the index created it gives

```shell
aql> select * from test.myset where status = 'key1'
0 rows in set (0.000 secs)
Error: (204) AEROSPIKE_ERR_INDEX

aql> select * from test.myset where state = 'key1'
0 rows in set (0.000 secs)
Error: (201) AEROSPIKE_ERR_INDEX_NOT_FOUND
```

Can someone help me with this. I searched for that error but found no information. Thank you.

Comment: Before we dig deeper, did you mean to do `where state =` instead of `where status =` ?

Comment: @Aaron, i tried using state and it is giving a different error. Updating the question accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Secondary indexes on MapKeys, MapValues, Lists  are supported by Aerospike, apart from Numeric, String and Geo2DSphere types.

For your scenario, you can query on the Mapkey as follows.

```
select * from test.myset in mapkeys where state='key1'
```

This should return the results.

In AQL, if you type help, you should get the following for queries

```
    SELECT <bins> FROM <ns>[.<set>]
    SELECT <bins> FROM <ns>[.<set>] WHERE <bin> = <value>
    SELECT <bins> FROM <ns>[.<set>] WHERE <bin> BETWEEN <lower> AND <upper>
    SELECT <bins> FROM <ns>[.<set>] WHERE PK = <key>
    SELECT <bins> FROM <ns>[.<set>] IN <indextype> WHERE <bin> = <value>
    SELECT <bins> FROM <ns>[.<set>] IN <indextype> WHERE <bin> BETWEEN <lower> AND <upper>
```

Similarly, you can run a query for the MapValue as well.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**:

As of Aerospike 3.8.1, [Secondary Index on List and Map are officially supported](http://www.aerospike.com/download/server/notes.html#3.8.1).

**Original Response**:

Query by secondary index on map keys, map values, or list values are 
[not officially supported yet](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/list-type-secondary-index-in-3-5-8/1200/10).

That said, the functionality and syntax is somewhat available. You need to:

1. Create a secondary index with type `MAPKEYS`, `MAPVALUES` or `LIST` (you're using type `STRING` at the moment)
2. `Select` as follows (you're missing the `IN MAPKEYS` part):

   `SELECT * FROM namespace.setname IN MAPKEYS WHERE bin = 'keyValue'`

The query syntax, as well as some other bits, is available if you type `help` while in the AQL console.